# CSS properties don't work in child diff

Tags: css, html, html5boilerplate

I made a parent **DIV** and a child **DIV**, the child **DIV** don't center and the width also don't work.
As well when I add a **IMG** in the child **DIV**,the properties also don't work.

Ex:

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
 <div id="child">
  <img id="big" .. />
 </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
  background: #999;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;

}

#parent #child {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#big {
  display: inline;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

(I made the test-site with the HTML5 Boilerplate http://html5boilerplate.com/ and is responsive)

I spent hours for solve this but no results :-(

Comment: looks good here: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5WfH/

Comment: Thx for the example. It's very useful to help solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Classes.

```
<div id="parent">
 <div class="child">
  <img id="big" .. />
 </div>
</div>

#parent {
  background: #999;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;

}

.child {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#big {
  display: inline;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how would that solve his problem? Although I do agree it's better coding standards, I fail to see how the problem was in id's

Comment: We from what I see, he wants to take the settings from "Parent" and apply them to other locations but in this specific one he will be using the child to allocate other settings. So instead of manually overriding etc, he can use a sub-class to do it. That and it is indeed better standards. Correct me if I'm wrong :P This is all hypothetical in my head